# Why is pip not upgrading cleanly on ubuntu 20.04 lts?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3

pip upgrade is not working, shows it upgraded by version is still showing old version

```
root@ubuntu:~# pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 11.9 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.3

root@ubuntu:~# pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

root@ubuntu:~# pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.3

root@ubuntu:~# pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

here are locations of python/pip

```
root@ubuntu:~# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
root@ubuntu:~# which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
root@ubuntu:~# which python
/usr/bin/python
root@ubuntu:~# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
root@ubuntu:~# python3 -V
Python 3.8.10
root@ubuntu:~# python -V
Python 3.8.10
root@ubuntu:~# pip3 -V
pip 22.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
root@ubuntu:~# pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

i will like to cleanly point pip to pip3, like i did with `apt install python-is-python3`

is there a package like `apt install pip-is-pip3`?

I am trying to shy away from creating symlinks manually myself

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much did this for now, but if anyone finds a non-manual way similar to `apt install python-is-python3` please post

```
root@ubuntu:~# rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip
root@ubuntu:~# ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip

root@ubuntu:~# rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
root@ubuntu:~# ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip

root@ubuntu:~# pip -V
pip 22.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: Be more careful next time. Trashing the system by many `pip`s in many locations will (and already did) your system unmanageable. I would suggest to remove all of `pip`s from `/usr/local/bin` and stick with `pip` and `pip3` from official Ubuntu repositories. Symlinks like `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip` → `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip` may cause unpredictable issues in future, I would suggest to avoid them.

Comment: well that is why i asked the question, how do we do something like `pip-is-pip3`? no one wants to be typing pip3

Comment: also pip was already in many places by default like i added in question, am not sure why python is always a pain to install...it should be easy to decide python2 or python3 and then install the python of choice as the default...should be that easy..not sure why it has to be rocket science to install python